# HTML5 canvas background image repeat

Tags: html, canvas, background, background-image

I have a html5 canvas that draws a sound wave. I have set the background as an background image, however, I want this background image to repeat. Can anyone tell me how I would do this and what I need to add into my code:

```
var backgroundImage = new Image(); 
backgroundImage.src = 'http://www.samskirrow.com/client-kyra/images/main-bg.jpg'; 
var canvas;
var context;

function init(c) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(c);
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    soundManager.onready(function() {
        initSound(clientID, playlistUrl);
    });
    aniloop();
}

function aniloop() {
    requestAnimFrame(aniloop);
    drawWave();
}

function drawWave() {

    var step = 10;
    var scale = 60;

    // clear
    context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);

    // left wave
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 256);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        context.lineTo(6 * i, 257 + waveLeft[i] * 80.);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();

    // right wave
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 256);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        context.lineTo(6 * i, 256 + waveRight[i] * 80.);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();
}

function updateWave(sound) {
    waveLeft = sound.waveformData.left;
}

return {
    init : init
};
})();
```

You can see this code in action here:
http://www.samskirrow.com/client-kyra

Comment: can't you use CSS for background repeat?

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib: Nope, not for images drawn onto the canvas.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the canvas' [`createPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_createPattern_example) function

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      img = new Image();

img.src = 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const ptrn = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat'); // Create a pattern with this image, and set it to "repeat".
  context.fillStyle = ptrn;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

(This is [the **fastest** of the 2 samples](http://jsperf.com/canvas-pattern-vs-manual-tiling)).

Or, try a manual implementation:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      img = new Image();

img.src = 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  for (let w = 0; w < canvas.width; w += img.width) {
    for (let h = 0; h < canvas.height; h += img.height) {
      context.drawImage(img, w, h);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Cerbrus do you know how to move the background pattern like this http://bdadam.com/blog/panning-and-scrolling-background-images-using-the-canvas-element.html

Comment: @Damsorian: you just linked to a tutorial that explains how that works.

Comment: To repeat a canvas pattern automatically (without manually creating copies) you can use `pattern.setTransform());`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern/setTransform