# How insert image instead of text-data in roullete wheel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, roulette-wheel-selection

I am using [this example](https://codepen.io/barney-parker/pen/OPyYqy) to create my own Roulette, but the thing is instead of values of $100.. etc in 'options' I need to use the image (the logo's).
How can I do this? Usage of

```
<input type="button" value="spin" style="float:left;" id='spin' />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

var options = ["$100", "$10", "$25", "$250", "$30", "$1000"];
var pattern1, pattern2;
var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx;

document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

var img1=new Image();
img1.onload=start;
img1.src="http://oi63.tinypic.com/2n1eyxk.jpg";
var img2=new Image();
img2.onload=start;
img2.src="http://oi63.tinypic.com/2n1eyxk.jpg";
var imgCount=2;
function start(){
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}
  pattern1=ctx.createPattern(img1,'repeat');
  pattern2=ctx.createPattern(img2,'repeat');
  draw();
}


function byte2Hex(n) {
  var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F,1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F,1);
}

function RGB2Color(r,g,b) {
    return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
}

function getColor(item, maxitem) {
  var phase = 0;
  var center = 128;
  var width = 127;
  var frequency = Math.PI*2/maxitem;

  red   = Math.sin(frequency*item+2+phase) * width + center;
  green = Math.sin(frequency*item+0+phase) * width + center;
  blue  = Math.sin(frequency*item+4+phase) * width + center;

  return RGB2Color(red,green,blue);
}

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 200;
    var textRadius = 160;
    var insideRadius = 125;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = options[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    } 

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
  var text = options[index]
  ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t/=d)*t;
  var tc = ts*t;
  return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

The usage of 'context.pattern' in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130129/how-to-fillstyle-with-images-in-canvas-html5) example didn't allow to execute the code and the Roulette.

Comment: Do you mean the values appearing in the center after each spin or the values appearing around the outside of the roulette wheel or both? Also, where are the logos you want to appear located relative to your code and what are the filenames?

Comment: The values which are inside the parts of roulette, you can see them at the example show. Logos just instead of them, there should be the possibility insert any logo. Anyway the answer below is seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of array of text i used an array of image url, and converted that to array  of image object using `map` so i can draw on canvas and where the text ws being rendered, rendered the image using `drawImage`

```js
var options = [
"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/128/Telegram-icon.png"];
var pattern1, pattern2;
var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx;

options = options.map(x => { 
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = x;
   return img;
});


document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);


function byte2Hex(n) {
  var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F,1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F,1);
}

function RGB2Color(r,g,b) {
    return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
}

function getColor(item, maxitem) {
  var phase = 0;
  var center = 128;
  var width = 127;
  var frequency = Math.PI*2/maxitem;

  red   = Math.sin(frequency*item+2+phase) * width + center;
  green = Math.sin(frequency*item+0+phase) * width + center;
  blue  = Math.sin(frequency*item+4+phase) * width + center;

  return RGB2Color(red,green,blue);
}

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 200;
    var textRadius = 160;
    var insideRadius = 125;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var img = options[i];
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 30, 30);
      //ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    } 

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
  //var text = options[index]
  var img = options[index];
       ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, 0, 30, 30);
 // ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t/=d)*t;
  var tc = ts*t;
  return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="spin" style="float:left;" id='spin' />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me - is it possible to show the image with the associated text in popup? (not alert function). I have this example [link](https://codepen.io/Valikhan/pen/KqqbJd)