# Simplest way to tile an Image in JS

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a PNG graphic I want to use as a background for my canvas in JS. It should be displayed in a tiled format. For this I'm currently doing something like this.

```
const ratioX = Math.ceil(canvas.width / image.width);
const ratioY = Math.ceil(canvas.height / image.height);
for (var x = 0; x < ratioX; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < ratioY; y++) {
        ctx.drawImage(image, x*image.width, y*image.height, image.width, image.height);
    }
}
```

It's working as intended, but the performance might get improved by not doing the calculations every frame, but buffering the bigger tiled version of my image. So I'm looking for a way to create this image as an instance of the `Image` class or any other class I can use for `drawImage()`.

At first I might need to get the image data (so the rgba info for every pixel). I've seen a way to do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image), using canvas's context, but do I really need to do that? Is there no simpler way?

The second step would be to create a drawable image object out of that data. How would I do that?

I would love to see a way that's equivalent to Java's `bufferedImage.getRgb(x, y)` and `bufferedImage.setRgb(x, y, color)`. Does something like this exist in JS?

Comment: HAve you tried http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_createpattern?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121719/html5-canvas-background-image-repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown [here in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_createpattern) you can use ctx `createPattern` to achieve what you want:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/50/50'
img.onload = function() {
  var pat = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 350, 350);
  ctx.fillStyle = pat;
  ctx.fill();
};
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=350 height=350/>
```

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong search keywords. I actually didn't know about `createPattern()` and that `fillStyle` can have other properties than a color. Thanks a lot, that solves my problem.